# Replace multiple substrings using strrep in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, str-replace

I have a big string (around 25M characters) where I need to replace multiple substrings of a specific pattern in it.

```
Frame 1
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........

Frame 2
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........

Frame 7670
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........
```

The substring I need to remove is the 'Frame #' and it occurs around 7670 times. I can give multiple search strings in strrep, using a cell array

```
strrep(text,{'Frame 1','Frame 2',..,'Frame 7670'},';')
```

However that returns a cell array, where in each cell, I have the original string with the corresponding substring of **one** of my input cell changed.

Is there a way to replace multiple substrings from a string, other than using regexprep? I noticed that it is considerably slower than strrep, that's why I am trying to avoid it.

With regexprep it would be:

```
regexprep(text,'Frame \d*',';')
```

and for a string of 25MB it takes around 47 seconds to replace all the instances.

**EDIT 1**: added the equivalent regexprep command

**EDIT 2**: added size of the string for reference, number of occurences for the substring and timing of execution for the regexprep

Comment: Your data appears to be numeric, why not use numeric operations rather than string operations if you are looking for speed? --- Furthermore, if you have the working regexp code, please show it.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin It's actually stored in a string, that's why I need to use string operations. I added the equivalent regexprep version that I am using at the moment.

Comment: Can you define how big it is in memory - maybe that's the issue with regexp. Also can you give some exact times - I wonder if it's the "search" or the "replacing" that's causing your slowdown.

Comment: `strrep` is fast, bit it's just not vectorized in a way that is useful for this kind of operation. If there are only a few known `'Frame #'` strings to be replaced you might just call `strrep` multiple times – even in a `for` loop. This is what I've done in some cases.

Comment: @bdecaf I added the size of the string, the number of occurences and the timing of the regexprep as an edit to the question.

Comment: would it be an option in stead of replacing to split the string at the 'Frame #' and concat it with ';'? Wonder how that would time.

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks! I just tried this, however it seems it's very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this can be done using only `textscan`, which is known to be very fast. Be specifying a `'CommentStyle'` the `'Frame #'` lines are stripped out. This may only work because these `'Frame #'` lines are on their own lines. This code returns the raw data as one big vector:

```
s = textscan(text,'%f','CommentStyle','Frame','Delimiter',',');
s = s{:}
```

You may want to know how many elements are in each frame or even reshape the data into a matrix. You can use `textscan` again (or before the above) to get just the data for the first frame:

```
f1 = textscan(text,'%f','CommentStyle','Frame 1','Delimiter',',');
f1 = s{:}
```

In fact, if you just want the elements from the first line, you can use this:

```
l1 = textscan(text,'%f,','CommentStyle','Frame 1')
l1 = l1{:}
```

However, the other nice thing about `textscan` is that you can use it to read in the file directly (it looks like you may be using some other means currently) using just `fopen` to get an FID. Thus the string data `text` doesn't have to be in memory.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! I didn't know about the 'CommentStyle' argument and it fits perfect for the occasion. I did some tests and the performance is slightly worse than the strrep solution though. It takes 0.064358" for the strrep and 0.0652884" for textscan for a small string (234k chars) and 4.798465" and 5.09043475" respectively for a larger string (25M chars). Reading the file directly is not possible, cause it also contains some headers that I need to scarp (although I tried it a headerless file and it was much slower than first reading the file and then using textscan)

Comment: I did a small error in the calculations and the numbers are: For strrep: 0.0629" and 4.687" (small and large string). For textscan: 0.0652" and 5.0904". Even though the textscan solution might be slightly slower, I like it's simplicity and robustness. Thanks @horchler!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in the end I found a way to go *around* the problem. Instead of using regexprep to change the substring, I remove the 'Frame ' substring (including whitespace, but not the number)

```
rawData = strrep(text,'Frame ','');
```

This results in something like this:

```
1
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........

2
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........

7670
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,34,0
0,1,2,3,34,12,3,4,0

...........
```

Then, I change all the commas (,) and newline characters (\n) into a semicolon (;), using again strrep, and I create a big vector with all the numbers

```
rawData = strrep(rawData,sprintf('\r\n'),';');
rawData = strrep(rawData,';;',';');
rawData = strrep(rawData,';;',';');
rawData = strrep(rawData,',',';');
rawData = textscan(rawData,'%f','Delimiter',';');
```

then I remove the unnecessary numbers (1,2,...,7670), since they are located at a specific point in the array (each frame contains a specific amount of numbers).

```
rawData{1}(firstInstance:spacing:lastInstance)=[];
```

And then I go on with my manipulations. It seems that the additional strrep and removal of the values from the array is much much faster than the equivalent regexprep. With a string of 25M chars with regexprep I can do the whole operation in about 47", while with this workaround it takes only 5"!

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Very clever. An order of magnitude is nice. You know that you're welcome to accept your answer if it is the best. I wonder if it would be possible to use `textscan` directly without using `strrep` at all.

Comment: I just played around with `textscan` a bit. I'd be interested to see how my answer stacks up to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Using [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
result = regexprep(text,'Frame [0-9]+','');
```

---

It's possible to avoid regular expressions as follows. I use `strrep` with suitable replacement strings that act as masks. The obtained strings are equal-length and are assured to be  aligned, and can thus be combined into the final result using the masks. I've also included the `;` you want. I don't know if it will be faster than `regexprep` or not, but it's definitely more fun :-)

```
% Data
text = 'Hello Frame 1 test string Frame 22 end of Frame 2 this'; %//example text
rep_orig = {'Frame 1','Frame 2','Frame 22'}; %//strings to be replaced.
%//May be of different lengths

% Computations    
rep_dest = cellfun(@(s) char(zeros(1,length(s))), rep_orig, 'uni', false);
%//series of char(0) of same length as strings to be replaced (to be used as mask)
aux = cell2mat(strrep(text,rep_orig.',rep_dest.'));
ind_keep = all(double(aux)); %//keep characters according to mask
ind_semicolon = diff(ind_keep)==1; %//where to insert ';' 
ind_keep = ind_keep | [ind_semicolon 0]; %// semicolons will also be kept
result = aux(1,:); %//for now
result(ind_semicolon) = ';'; %//include `;`
result = result(ind_keep); %//remove unwanted characters
```

With these example data:

```
>> text

text =

Hello Frame 1 test string Frame 22 end of Frame 2 this

>> result

result =

Hello ; test string ; end of ; this
```

Comment: It would seem the asker already has the `regexprep` expression.

Comment: Indeed, I have a working solution with regexprep, I am just wondering if there is a way to do it with strrep (or something else), because regexprep is lacking in speed compared to strrep

Comment: Note that if `text` is large, as indicated in the question, your second version makes as many copies of it as there are strings to be replaced (see the variable `aux`). Such a scheme (replicating the search text in a cell array) seems to be the only way to use `strrep` to do this. I can't imagine that it's efficient for large strings. But who knows, it may still be faster than `regexp`.

Comment: @horchler Totally agree with you

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I tried it out, and for a smaller string (325k chars) it is actually much slower than regexprep (0.007322" for regexprep vs 1.113859" for strrep). I tried it for the longer string (25M chars) and it took so long that I had to stop it. Probably the problem is (as @horchler mentions) that it creates as many copies (7.6k) as the strings to be replaced. So the memory demand is huge (calculating it roughly, I get some 180GB of memory). So I think I'll stick to regexprep for the moment :)

Comment: @Nakano You could always use strrep with a loop that overwrites a single result string, instead of my `cellfun` which gives different result strings and then combines them. Memory won't be an issue then. Time I don't know